# Unit Test with Generics types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, testing, nunit

I want to test a unit test with generics, and I am STRUGGLING to find the right way.

I have this

```
[TestCase(typeof(CalendarGeneralCsv), typeof(CalendarGeneralCsvMap), 121)]
public void ReadFromCsvFileWithConfigurationMapTest<T,Tmap>(T t, Tmap tmap, int totalRowsExptected)
{
   //Arrange

   //Act
    var records = csvService.ReadFileCsv<T, Tmap>(_csvToRead, ",") as IEnumerable<object>;

     var result = new List<object>(records);

     //Assert
     result.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
     result.Should().HaveCount(totalRowsExptected);
}
```

The error is in this line

```
  var records = csvService.ReadFileCsv<T, Tmap>(_csvToRead, ",") as IEnumerable<object>;
```

Saying that T, and Tmap must be a reference type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not usually reply where there is already several answers and one is accepted, but they all seem to be based on the assumption that test methods can't be generic. They definitely can. My memory tells me this was once well-documented, but it doesn't seem to be any longer - or my memory is wrong - which explains why you might not think it's possible.

It's possible a generic solution may not be best here, but it seems like a fun thing to try and may either be better or clarify why the accepted solution is better. I can only go so far with the info already provided, but if jolynice will collaborate, maybe we can learn something. :-)

So... here is an initial shot at a solution, which I'll edit if more info comes back.

The original solution in the question causes an error because the constraints in the generic method `ReadFileCsv<T, Tmap>(...)` are not met. We don't know what they are, but from the error they include `T : class` and `Tmap : class`. So the first step to a correct answer is to reproduce all the constraints of the method being called on the test method itself.

UPDATE: This code doesn't actually work. Short story, I have the feature locally and I thought it had been added to NUnit but it has not. See UPDATE text below as well...

```
[TestCase(typeof(CalendarGeneralCsv), typeof(CalendarGeneralCsvMap), 121)]
public void ReadFromCsvFileWithConfigurationMapTest<T,Tmap>(int totalRowsExptected)
    where T : class
    where Tmap : class
{
   //Arrange
    
   //Act
    var records = csvService.ReadFileCsv<T, Tmap>(_csvToRead, ",") as IEnumerable<object>;
    
     var result = new List<object>(records);
    
     //Assert
     result.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
     result.Should().HaveCount(totalRowsExptected);
}
```

UPDATE in response to @Jannes comment

You can create a generic method without parameters in C#. If you used such a method as a test method, NUnit would need to know the actual types to use to call it. Unfortunately, there is no such way.

Currently, NUnit can only deduce the actual types from arguments you provide. That means there has to be at least one argument for each parameter Type of the generic method.

This is clearly a gap in NUnit and it has been discussed in various issues on GitHub. So far, no proposal has been accepted. See issues 150, 1215, 2562 and 3576 at https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues for example.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I don't use NUnit, but in XUnit, the parameters of the equivalent of `TestCase` attribute would be instances of the generic types being used. So something like this: `[TestCase(new CalendarGeneralCsv(), new CalendarGeneralCsvMap(), 121)]`

Comment: Hello Charlie, Thanks you to participate to this problem. ;) , I try your solution and I still have the reference. Error CS0311 The type 'Tmap' cannot be used as type parameter 'TMap' in the generic type or method 'CsvServices.ReadFileCsv<T, TMap>(string, string)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Tmap' to 'CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap'

Comment: jolynice: Updated the code example. If you see further errors, please post the declaration (i.e. the header) of the method `ReadFileCsv`.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this does not seem to work (anymore?). Simply results in "Arguments provided for method with no parameters". Your answer is literally the only place on internet where this construct is even mentioned at all.

Comment: @Jannes If you get that message, then your test method doesn't take parameters. It's currently not possible to have a generic test method without parameters in NUnit. See my updated note on the question for details.

Comment: ok, so now you're saying what the rest of the internet was also saying: nunit can only deduce type from actual argument values. There's no way to pass in typeparams if they're not used in arguments. I guess I was misled by your answer with the example code where you're clearly doing just that. As well as the comment that says "But if the intial args provided are types and there is no corresponding parameter, then they are taken as type args."

Comment: @Jannes Yes that's right. I wrote code to handle initial type arguments, which I thought released, but apparently not. That was my impression when I responded to this issue back in early 2019. As far as I can tell, that wrong answer was up for about 11 hours back then before I changed it. Did I miss something? I can't find the comment you quoted anywhere.

Comment: Ok thank you for promoting this feature and even writing it. As well as answering questions here. Very unfortunate that it never made it in. Seems quite useful to me. Maybe better to put a warning on the top of this answer that it doesn't actually work (yet). Could save future people a bit of confusion. The example code in the answer still shows the not-working solution. Thanks also for making TestFixtureSource with generic type support. I've used that too. BTW: I was referring to the third comment to this answer (starts with "DavidG: Normally...").

Comment: @Jannes Ah... I edited the text but not the example. I'll do as you suggest. The comment to Davidg is wrong but I left it there because it's history... i.e. I really said that wrong thing, and later corrected it in subsequent comments. But maybe you're right that it could confuse people so I'll delete it. Unfortunately, the platform doesn't allow editiing comments.

Comment: Your point about history certainly has merit, although I think that's not the priority on this website. It's getting good questions and good answers without having to scroll through endless pages of discussion as is the case on more typical forums. Even this discussion is getting off topic, I presume. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you don't plan on using multiple `TestCase` attributes on your test with different types, then there's no need to give the test any generic parameters. You could just explicitly pass the types into the type parameters:

```
public void ReadFromCsvFileWithConfigurationMapTest()
{
    //Arrange

    //Act
    var records = csvService.ReadFileCsv<CalendarGeneralCsv, CalendarGeneralCsvMap>(_csvToRead, ",") as IEnumerable<object>;

    var result = new List<object>(records);

    //Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    result.Should().HaveCount(121);
}
```

If you do however want to run the same test case for multiple types/values, you can extract the actual test logic to a generic method. Then you can create a new test for each set of data that you want to test, explicitly passing the types into the generic method:

```
[Test]
public void ReadFromCsvFileWithConfigurationMapTest() => ReadFromCsvFile<CalendarGeneralCsv, CalendarGeneralCsvMap>(121);

[Test]
public void ReadFromCsvFileWithOtherMapTest() => ReadFromCsvFile<CalendarGeneralCsv, OtherGeneralCsvMap>(151);

private void ReadFromCsvFile<T, TMap>(int expectedValue)
{
    //Arrange

    //Act
    var records = csvService.ReadFileCsv<T, TMap>(_csvToRead, ",") as IEnumerable<object>;

    var result = new List<object>(records);

    //Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    result.Should().HaveCount(expectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Hello devNull, the solution you gave , I´ve already implemented, but I need to test multiple generics types. Thanks anyway for your anwser.

Comment: @jolynice I've updated my answer with another option that allows you to write multiple tests for the same test case, passing in different Types/values for each test.

Answer (score 2):

Although there's already an accepted answer *(NOTE: it has changed since I originally posted)*, I'd like to offer an alternative way of using reflection.  Split the test method into two methods, a **springboard method** and a **generic test method**.  There are several advantages:

- The generic test method looks more like any other test method.  It doesn't have unrelated reflection mixed in.
- The generic test method can be stepped through normally, also because it doesn't have unrelated reflection mixed in.
- Changes to the component under test are more likely to trigger a compiler error in the test project so you know that the generic test method, and probably the springboard method, need to be updated.  Plus, because of where the exception is being thrown, it's clearer at run-time that it's because of the supporting reflection and not how the component is used.
- The springboard method doesn't need to know anything about the component under test, only how to call the generic test method.
- The pattern can be reproduced easily and consistently because there's very little variation.

Here's an example based on the question and the accepted answer:

```
[TestCase(typeof(CalendarGeneralCsv), typeof(CalendarGeneralCsvMap), 121)]
[TestCase(typeof(CalendarCustomCsv), typeof(CalendarCustomCsvMap), 80)]
public void ReadFromCsvFileWithConfigurationMapTest(Type t, Type tmap, int totalRowsExpected)
{
    GetType().GetMethod(nameof(GenericReadFromCsvFileWithConfigurationMapTest))
        .MakeGenericMethod(t, tmap)                         // <-- Type parameters go here
        .Invoke(this, new object[] { totalRowsExpected });  // <-- inputs go here
}

public void GenericReadFromCsvFileWithConfigurationMapTest<T, Tmap>(int totalRowsExpected)
    where T : class
    where Tmap : class
{
    // Arrange

    // Act
    var records = csvService.ReadFileCsv<T, Tmap>(_csvToRead, ",") as IEnumerable<object>;

    // Assert
    records.Should().NotBeNull();

    var result = new List<object>(records);

    result.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    result.Should().HaveCount(totalRowsExptected);
}
```

**Points of Interest**

It uses `GetType()` because it's looking for a method on the same type (the test class).  This reduces variation so that the pattern can be reproduced more easily.

The generic test method has a different name (doesn't matter what it is as long as it's different) so that the `GetMethod` call doesn't need to specify the parameter types.  There should be only one method by that name and it's public so it doesn't need `BindingFlags`, either.  Alternatively, you could make it private, just add `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`.  *Note: not all framework versions have an overload taking `BindingFlags`. You'll have to find an alternative if you want to make it private.*

The generic test method needs to include the constraints.  That makes the constraints a formal part of your test.  The reflection will fail at run-time either way if the constraints aren't met, but having them on the generic test method, you're likely to write a better test from the start.  You mentioned that `T` and `Tmap` must be reference types so those are included above.

Finally, your springboard is capable of defining multiple test cases, as you've indicated you need to be able to do, so I included another calendar and mapping above.

Comment: Hello madreflection, devNull,  DavidG, Charlie and Nikosi, Thank you all for all the solution you gave. I appreciate a lot this community.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using reflection to invoke the generic subject under test

```
[TestCase(typeof(CalendarGeneralCsv), typeof(CalendarGeneralCsvMap), 121)]
public void ReadFromCsvFileWithConfigurationMapTest(Type t, Type tmap, int totalRowsExptected) {
    //Arrange

    //...

    var serviceType = csvService.GetType();
    var method = serviceType.GetMethod("ReadFileCsv");
    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(t, tmap);

    var parameters = new object[] { _csvToRead, "," };

    //Act
    var records = genericMethod.Invoke(csvService, parameters) as IEnumerable<object>;
    //Above same as csvService.ReadFileCsv<T, Tmap>(_csvToRead, ",") as IEnumerable<object>;

    //Assert
    records.Should().NotBeNull();

    var result = new List<object>(records);

    result.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    result.Should().HaveCount(totalRowsExptected);
}
```

Using the `csvService`, get the type via `GetType()`

```
var serviceType = csvService.GetType();
```

in order to have access to its member information.

Find the desired member to be invoked by name

```
var method = serviceType.GetMethod("ReadFileCsv");
```

and using the provided type arguments for the generic arguments

```
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(t, tmap);
```

The generic member can be invoked on the service instance with the passed arguments.

```
 var records = genericMethod.Invoke(csvService, new object[] { _csvToRead, "," }) as IEnumerable<object>;
```

Comment: Whoa Nikosi, great, it´s working. I like your explanation, easy to understand. 5 start. I just change the Invoke parameter. The second parameter its object[] parameter, so I create this . var records = genericMethod.Invoke(csvService,  new object[] { _csvToRead, "," }) as IEnumerable<object>;

Comment: Your answer solves the problem but could you please remove or edit the first line? I can imagine this answer being cited as demonstration that there are no generic test methods in NUnit. There definitely are, but I'm not sure it would be the best solution here... However, for fun, I'll see if I can write one next.